# Rotating a rectangle based on Mouse X and Y position

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I've been working on this and trying to get it to work but now I am pretty much stumped.

I want this rectangle to follow this mouse position and rotate correctly. It's following the mouse but the my angle rotate seems off. Any help or guidance, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here's the code that has the angle in it:

```
function createBoat() {
    var angle = Math.atan2(
            boat.y - mousePos.y,
            boat.x - mousePos.x
        ) * 180 / Math.PI;
    ship_context.rotate(angle);
    ship_context.fillRect(boat.x, boat.y, boat.width, boat.height); // create some shape, there is nothing on the canvas yet
}
```

Here's my loop

```
function loop() {
    ship_context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    moveBoat();
    time = Date.now();
    createBoat();

    setTimeout(loop, 1000/60);
}
```

Here's a demo: http://staging.interactivemechanics.com/chop/row3.html

---

Also, sidenote, I am working with basic shapes right now. But I plan to translate everything to images. The rectangle will be a boat and I have a separate page where I have leaves in a pond moving. I have that part working with the collision detection too. I want to know if a library would be better to use here or if I should stick with canvas?

Here's the other demo: http://staging.interactivemechanics.com/chop/row2.html with the moving stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rotate only the boat, you first need to translate (let's call it fixate) to the position of the canvas, and rotate on that point. In order to avoid your ship to over-rotate, we also need to reset the rotation after we're done drawing the ship

Try this:

```
function createBoat() {
    var angle = Math.atan2(
            boat.y - mousePos.y,
            boat.x - mousePos.x
        ) * 180 / Math.PI;
    ship.context.save(); //save the settings of the canvas
    ship_context.translate(boat.x+boat.width/2,boat.y+boat.height/2); //move focus to boat position (middle of the boat)
    ship_context.rotate(angle);
    ship_context.fillRect(-boat.width/2, -boat.height/2); // create some shape, there is nothing on the canvas yet
    ship_context.restore(); //putting everything back in place
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, I will have to read up more on that, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial explaining about rotation of an image, including the save(), rotate() and restore() http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/